# SFTP access to OSX stopped working

Tags: macos, ssh, file-transfer, android, sftp

I have enabled `Remote Login` in System Preferences in order to sftp files from my Macbook to my android devices. On those I have AndFTP installed and it used to work without problem. Now I don't think I've done anything to my system lately, but I am no longer able to connect to the Macbook, neither from my phone nor my tablet, both with Android 7.

- `sftp localhost` works
- The other direction (FTPServer App on Android), FileZilla on the Mac stopped working as well. Upon connection, the server says `500 SSH-2.0-PUTTY_LOCAL:_MAR_20_2017_16:50:29 not understood`. I am confused as to the obsolete date in this message, but understand nothing else about it.
- I have updated my phone to android 7, but the tablet shows the same behaviour
- using `sftp` from the command line to sftp into android also does not work, the server has gives the same 500 error just with a different client string

What tools can I use on macOS or Android to debug this problem?

Comment: Already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1199633/what-can-i-do-about-a-500-ssh-not-understood-error)

Comment: That thread is more about the other direction, not phone to laptop.

Comment: Certainly you should not connect with one protocol to the other.

Comment: Have you check that the date and time is correctly set on both devices? SSL requires the date to be set fairly correctly and a bad date on either device would explain the error message date.